# TestNG cannot contact RemoteTestNG on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am using Eclipse to run some TestNG tests. The test used to work on the environment but I cannot run the tests using TestNG anymore. The error I get is this:
Couldn't contact the RemoteTestNG client. Uncheck the 'Use Project "testng.jar' option from your Project properties and try again.
Reason: Timeout while trying to contact RemoteTestNG."

I did what the error message says but it still fails. This time with this error:
"Coultn't contact the RemoteTestNG client. Make sure you don't have an older version of testng.jar on your classpath"

I am running it on Ubuntu and Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem. Recently, I moved my desktop and due to that there was a new IP assigned to my computer. Since I hardcoded previous IP in my /etc/hosts file, the localhost ip lookup was not working anymore. After fixing the IP in the /etc/hosts file, it started to work again.